# How do I properly override instance methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

I've been learning Ruby for a class and have been writing a sample game. Here is a bit of one of my classes:

```
  class Player
    def askIfTake
      puts("Would you like to take a card? > ")
      input = gets.chomp
      input.downcase!
      if input == "y" or input == "yes"
        return 1
      elsif input == "n" or input == "no"
        return 0
      else
        puts("Invalid input. Please type y or n.")
        return askIfTake
      end
    end
  end
```

I then have another class:

```
  class PlayerAI < Player
    def initialize
      super
    end

    def askIfTake
      puts("this is an AI")
      return rand(2)
    end
  end
```

The problem is, when I create an instance of PlayerAI, and attempt to call askIfTake from that instance, it calls the method declared in the Player class. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. I tested it (knowing it would be fine) and it worked for me:

```
>> PlayerAI.new
=> #<PlayerAI:0x00000103889308>
>> PlayerAI.new.askIfTake
this is an AI
```

You are doing this in the correct way. Check if you have any spelling mistakes. Incidentally, in Ruby the method usually uses underscores: `PlayerAI.new.ask_if_take`. Or better, with a question mark: `PlayerAI.new.will_take?`.

Comment: @AohmZ: you'll get faster at picking typos over time; eventually you'll have a "sixth [programming] sense" and will be able to spot bugs before they even occur :)